# @font-face looks very odd on Windows only, but only when font-weight is 400

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm using the font [Signika](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Signika). It works perfectly everywhere (Mac, Android, iOS) except for Windows (no matter which version), where it looks oddly squished all browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera):

[image: Windows, why?]

That's at `font-weight: 400`. But when I change the font-weight to 100, I get the light version of Signika, perfectly rendered.

*Why?*

So far, my fix is to detect if the user is using Windows and just change font-weight to 100, then fake the extra weight with text-shadow), but I still want to know the root of the problem.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Signika";
    src: url("fonts/signika-webfont.eot");
    src: url('fonts/signika-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('fonts/signika-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('fonts/signika-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),url('fonts/signika-webfont.svg#Signika') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Signika";
    src: url("fonts/signika-light-webfont.eot");
    src: url('fonts/signika-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('fonts/signika-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),url('fonts/signika-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),url('fonts/signika-light-webfont.svg#Signika') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: Signika, sans-serif;
    color: #181818;
    font-weight: 400;
    clear: both;
}
```

**Edit**:

I re-downloaded the .eot and .woff files from Font-Squirrel. I also realized something odd: when I then tested my site on browserstack.com (specifying Windows 8.1 and Chrome 35) and browsershots.org (specifying Chrome 35), the font is rendered just fine. But when I borrow my sister's computer (Windows 8.1) and checked my site using Chrome 35, the font was oddly squished. So I'm now working on setting up virtual hosts.

Comment: Does it render properly if you use the hosted version? `<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />`

Comment: Not reproduceable on Windows 7 (on Chrome, IE, Firefox) using hosted version as suggested by @TiesonT. You may have broken version(s) of the font, and the question does not specify how the font files were generated.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I re-downloaded the .otf file from Font-Squirrel and re-created the .eot and .woff files. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "not reproduceable" – is the font not wonky on your end when you use the hosted version?

Comment: “Not reproduceable” means that the problem cannot be reproduced with the code provided when a hosted version is used; there is nothing “wonky” in any heading element.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem today. It is caused by the font-squirrel converter.

When you choose expert mode, make sure `Truetype Hinting` is set to `Font Squirrel` and `X-height Matching` is `none`. Having any of these options to something different, cripples the font. I am not sure what the other modes (basic and optimal) do, but you might want to use expert to be sure.

After refreshing browser cache the font did fine on windows.

Answer (score -1):

Reconverting my fonts into .woff fixed this issue for me.